# Forms on cockpit CMS

Tags: php, sqlite, cockpit, cockpit-cms

I'm trying to build a form using cockpit CMS. Link : http://localhost/misc/cockpit .

As in the docs, I have created a token and given '*' privilage and using it in the endpoint like this:
http://localhost/misc/cockpit/api/forms/submit/leads?token=eb29a1e1bc5d90cbd8a6599b3363ee . My form name is 'leads'. When is try to submit form using POST call with JSON object with a form property, i'm getting 404 error.

```
{
    "form": {
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2"
    }
}
```

Wanted to know where i'm going wrong.

Comment: `404 error` means the URL doesn't exist/was not found

Comment: I know that. but if don't use a security token or use the wrong token, I get {"error":"Unauthorized"} error.

Comment: be aware that cockpit api is case sensitive, are you sure your form name is 'leads'? for example can you access `http://localhost/misc/cockpit/forms/form/leads`?

Comment: I just had the same problem, and the solution was to correct the JSON string that was posted, now your JSON looks good, but check how you are sending it!